# Does the open graph image uploader API have a "profanity" filter?

Tags: facebook, image, api, upload

I have the permissions and uploading of photos working for my app, through open graph.

However, I'm wondering if I need to implement a flagging system to filter inappropriate pitures, or will the API detect and restrict the uploading of profane images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mauro; I am pretty sure that nobody has ever written software that can reliably decide whether a picture exceeds a specified level of profanity. Therefore I am pretty sure that no Facebook API can do it.

(Let's not forget the fact that someone would have to define the precise meaning of 'profane', which everybody will disagree on.)